# How to fill null values by previous non null based on categories

Tags: c#, linq

I have data set like below and need to extrapolate all null "Price" values by previous non null "Price" value. This looks simply by there are few more categories which I need to consider - Cat1, Cat2, DateG and TimeG - which I have this "Price" for.

```
class DataLoad
    {
        public int DateG { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeG { get; set; }
        public string Cat1 { get; set; }
        public string Cat2 { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }
        public int? Volume { get; set; }

        public static List<DataLoad> GetSomeData()
        {
            return new List<DataLoad>()
            {
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A1", DateG = 20190601, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("00:11:00.0000000"), Price = null, Volume = 4209},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A1", DateG = 20190602, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("12:22:00.0000000"), Price = 123.54, Volume = 2109},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190602, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("15:33:00.0000000"), Price = 213.44, Volume = 2119},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190605, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("20:31:00.0000000"), Price = null, Volume = 1134},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190605, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("21:33:00.0000000"), Price = null, Volume = 1824},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190605, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("21:34:00.0000000"), Price = 214.74, Volume = 1111},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190606, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("23:41:00.0000000"), Price = 223.64, Volume = 3456},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B1", DateG = 20190512, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("11:41:00.0000000"), Price = 135.77, Volume = 1956},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B1", DateG = 20190513, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("12:34:00.0000000"), Price = null, Volume = 3457},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B2", DateG = 20190514, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("08:11:00.0000000"), Price = 123.54, Volume = 9873},
                new DataLoad {Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B2", DateG = 20190514, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("15:21:00.0000000"), Price = null, Volume = 2890},

            };
        }
    }
```

I was wondering to sort out the data set based on DateG, TimeG, Cat1 and Cat2 and then apply some logic but I always end up with bunch of for loops which over complicates it and I cannot achieve desired output in final.

Desired output should look like below filled prices (regardless ordering of DateG, TimeG, Cat1, Cat2):

```
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A1", DateG = 20190601, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("00:11:00.0000000"), Price = 123.54, Volume = 4209
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A1", DateG = 20190602, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("12:22:00.0000000"), Price = 123.54, Volume = 2109
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190602, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("15:33:00.0000000"), Price = 213.44, Volume = 2119
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190605, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("20:31:00.0000000"), Price = 213.44, Volume = 1134
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190605, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("21:33:00.0000000"), Price = 213.44, Volume = 1824
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190605, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("21:34:00.0000000"), Price = 214.74, Volume = 1111
Cat1 = "A", Cat2 = "A2", DateG = 20190606, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("23:41:00.0000000"), Price = 223.64, Volume = 3456
Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B1", DateG = 20190512, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("11:41:00.0000000"), Price = 135.77, Volume = 1956
Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B1", DateG = 20190513, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("12:34:00.0000000"), Price = 135.77, Volume = 3457
Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B2", DateG = 20190514, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("08:11:00.0000000"), Price = 123.54, Volume = 9873
Cat1 = "B", Cat2 = "B2", DateG = 20190514, TimeG = DateTime.Parse("15:21:00.0000000"), Price = 123.54, Volume = 2890
```

Is there any simple way how to do that with/without linq.

Comment: 1st Ascending order you have given with DateG, so B - B1 will be the 1st item as per the record.

Comment: Yeah, it is just to imagine how prices are filled by previous non null values.

Comment: In your example, I see how you're filling the price with the previous value except I don't understand how that works for the first entry. Wouldn't it's previous value be nothing? Or, in that case, does it need to check for its _next_ value? (Assuming you're reading top is first, bottom is last)

Comment: What if all prices were `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of options here.

- You could use [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) which has some methods that may work (e.g. `Lag/Lead` or `FillForward/FillBackward`).
- You could write your own decently simple extension method that does the filling for you.

### Using MoreLinq:

There are quite a few ways you could do this with MoreLinq, but I'll just show an example using the `Lag` extension.

```
var result = GetSomeData() 
    // Do ordering if you want
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateG)
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.TimeG)
    .ThenByDescending(c1 => c1.Cat1)
    .ThenByDescending(c2 => c2.Cat2)
    // Add the filling logic with .Lag()
    .Lag(1, (current, previous) =>
    {
        if(previous != null) current.name = current.name ?? previous.name;
        return current;
    }).ToList();
```

The one downside to this is that it doesn't provide the "backfilling" that you might need. If you had `null` prices at the beginning of the list, those would stay null and not be filled. You could get around this by manually handling those cases or running it on the reversed list (probably not recommended). Another thing to note is that this will edit the actual objects in the list and not create new ones which I typically prefer to avoid when dealing with LINQ. You could edit the selector to change that behavior.

### Custom Extension Method:

Here's one that I came up with:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Fill<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> resultSelector)
{
    var backFilled = false;
    var previous = default(TSource);
    var backFill = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var elm in source)
    {
        if (predicate(elm))
        {
            if (!backFilled)
            {
                backFill.Add(elm);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return resultSelector(previous, elm);
            }
        }
        else if (!backFilled)
        {
            // We've found our first element to be able to backfill with
            for (int i = 0; i < backFill.Count; i++)
            {
                yield return resultSelector(elm, backFill[i]);
            }
            backFilled = true;
            yield return elm;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return elm;
        }
        previous = elm;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

Here the first parameter is a condition that I want to fill on. In your case it would be if the data `DataLoad.Price` is null. So something like:

```
data => data.Price == null
```

If that condition evaluates to true, it then calls the `handler` function with the current value and the previous value. Yours would look something like this:

```
(prev, curr) => 
{ 
    curr.Price = prev.Price;
    return curr;
}
```

Putting that all together you get:

```
var result = GetSomeData()
    // Do ordering/filtering/grouping here
    .Fill(
        data => data.Price == null,
        (prev, curr) => 
        { 
            curr.Price = prev.Price;
            return curr;
        })
    .ToList();
```

Here's a link to a [demo](https://repl.it/repls/DullJointTelephones) that you can play around with.

The benefit of this is that you get more control over what's happening when filling while still making the function decently generic. You could apply this to any IEnumerable and have it still work. This also does the "backfilling" which the MoreLinq query didn't do out of the box.

**Note:** This still edits the existing objects in the list in place, but a different selector would fix that.

Comment: You gave me great idea how to finish this exercise. Thank you so much! Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DataLoad> result =
    DataLoad.GetSomeData()
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateG)
            .ThenByDescending(t => t.TimeG)
            .ThenByDescending(c1 => c1.Cat1)
            .ThenByDescending(c2 => c2.Cat2)
            .ToList();
```

Your desired output example is confusing, but if i anticipated what you want, this query should help.

Comment: OP wants to set `Price` property. Your code will only sort records

Comment: Sorry, I forgot remove sorting part which is not considered as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Linq will note provide you the best performant approaches.

```
DataLoad.GetSomeData()
    .Where(x => x.Price == null)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        x.Price = list.First(v => v.Cat1 == x.Cat1 &&
                                  v.Cat2 == x.Cat2 &&
                                  v.Price != null)
                      .Price;
    });
```

If your data is already ordered, you can perform an index select based on the previous value when the price is null. Another example is using a local function with recursion and order by:

```
var orderedList = GetSomeData()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Cat1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Cat2)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Price);

var result = orderedList.Select((e, i) =>
{
    e.Price = e.Price ?? GetPrice(i);
    return e;
});

double GetPrice(int index)
{
    return orderedList.ElementAt(++index).Price
           ?? GetPrice(index);
}
```

Using the same approach logic you can write for loops to do the same thing.